# ASP.NET Unity.MVC DI with EF context

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, unity-container

I'm using Unity.MVC for DI in my ASP.NET MVC 4.6 app. I have a service interface passed into the controller and that's working great. Now I want to pass in an interface to the EF context to the service but I'm not sure how to do this. I've read EF has this IObjectContextAdapter that I could pass into my service ctor and that works, but I need to then query the actual tables on inside my service from this context but because it's an IObjectContextAdapter it doesn't know my tables. How do I do this?

```
 public class ContactService : IContactService
    {
        //private ContactsEntities context;
        private IObjectContextAdapter context;

        // test ctor
        public ContactService(IObjectContextAdapter ctx)
        {
            context = ctx;
        }

        // prod ctor
        public ContactService()
        {
            context = new ContactsEntities();
        }

        List<Contact> GetAllContacts()
        {
            return (from c in context.ObjectContext.?? // I need to query the Contacts table that would be attached to the actual context I pass in but still keep the decoupling from using an Interface passed into the ctor

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IObjectContextAdapter` is the type of `ObjectContext` property of `DbContext`.

You should subclass `DbContext` e.g. `ContactsDatabaseContext`

```
public class ContactsDatabaseContext : DbContext, IContactsDatabaseContext
{
  // ...
}
```

And then just register your `ContactsDatabaseContext` with your IoC container. Something like this:

```
container.RegisterType<IContactsDatabaseContext, ContactsDatabaseContext>();
```

Your `ContactsDatabaseContext` class and `IContactsDatabaseContext` interface should have properties of type `DbSet<T>` that refer to your tables e.g.:

```
IDbSet<BrandDb> Users { get; set; }
```

UPDATE:

Since you are using a generated file, then do this:

```
public partial class ContactsDatabaseContext : IContactsDatabaseContext
{
  // Expose the DbSets you want to use in your services
}
```

Comment: I'm doing database first so touching the autogenerated ContactContext file is a no go right? Since it's autogenerated.

Comment: It's been a long time since I last used an EF generated file but that means you already that class. That's good. You may now register it. If you want you can still add the interface (if not already there by declaring the class with the `partial` keyword and assigning the interface. This way, you won't have to change the generated code in anyway (that's what partial is for).

Comment: Yeah, that helps. Kind of a bummer I have to maintain this manually vs EF doing it for me and creating an interface automatically and managing the DbSet's for me too. I can see forgetting to add DbSet's to the interface if I add tables to the database and update the model. With MS pushing DI so much you'd think they would do this for us. Thanks.

Comment: Good point. At least you have a way forward. Anyway, you'll find it's not too hard to remember as you'll have to add those properties to the interface when you want to use them... @user441521, if it works you should accept.

Comment: The time to accept wasn't up yet. I tried :). Good now.

Comment: Actually this is giving me an error on the registering line: There is no implicit reference conversion from ContactsEntities to IContactsEntities

Comment: In your partial class definition, make sure that `ContactsEntities` implements `IContactsEntities`. See the edit I had made with the partial class thing. This is because there is a Type restriction on the registration method that says that the first must be extended or implemented by the second.

Comment: Yeah, it is. I have: public partial class ContactsEntities : IContactsEntities

Comment: Do you have this namespace `Microsoft.Practices.Unity`? It is necessary because of the `UnityContainerExtensions`.

Comment: Also, the interface type must come `first`.

Comment: Alternatively, try not using the extension method: `container.RegisterType(from: typeof(InterfaceName), to: typeof(ImplementationName));`

Comment: Using the RegisterType() function removed the error. That's odd because I can do a normal type with the extension method with another interface I made, but maybe something about a partial class? Will see if it works but it does compile now.

Comment: So actually it was because my partial class was in a different namespace so they were looked at as 2 different classes. Sorry, my bad. I haven't worked much with partial classes.